# JUnit, Why pass the test?(android)

Tags: java, android, junit

Sorry for my english. I created simple activity, and simple test. Method in activity:

```
public boolean checkEditText(int number) {
       return number > 0 ? true : false;
    }
```

Test

```
public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    public MainActivityTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }


    public void testCheckNumber() {
        MainActivity activity = getActivity();

        boolean action = activity.checkEditText(0);
        Assert.assertTrue(action);
    }


}
```

Why pass the test?

If i do like this:

```
 Assert.assertTrue(false);
```

it pass test too.

Comment: Sounds like your test isn't being run.

Comment: `return number > 0 ? true : false;` is the same as `return number > 0;`.

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks, but if i do like this `Assert.assertTrue(false);` it pass test. I cant undertand why

Comment: "but if i do like this" Yes. That assertion would fail *if your test method is actually run*. It doesn't fail, so the test method isn't being run.

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks, sorry for my stupit qestions but its for me not clear. Ok, my test method not run?  But android studio show that method run [image](http://take.ms/DELxP). Its test pass too, i say that `activity = null` and then check `Assert.assertNotNull(activity);`, but everething ok. `public void testActivityExistNull() { MainActivity activity = null; Assert.assertNotNull(activity);}`

Comment: Have you try to add @Test annotation on your `testCheckNumber` method ? You may also override `runTest` method and invoke `testCheckNumber()` in its body...